# How to keep users on the same page after refreshing with react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I have a project where a user have login to his dashboard, after user logged in he can navigate to certain pages (links)

An example of the pages he can visit is:

```
Profile
    -View profile
    -Edit profile
```

the main route which renders the dashboard is

> localhost/dashboard/home

When user click on **View profile** link he will be redirected to the view page which is rendered by the route

> dashboard/patient/:patientCode/profile

Now, whenever I refresh the *View profile** page I will be redirected back to the dashboard page, this behavior is caused by re-rendering the **App** component and check the auth state of the user will be **AUTHENTICATED** and thus will be redirected back to **/dashboard/home**.

My question is how to take the user back to where he was before refreshing the browser?!

Note that i'm using redux for state management

here is my App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkAuthStatus();
  }

  checkAuthStatus() {
    const accessToken = sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken");
    if (!accessToken) {
      this.props.signOut();
      this.props.history.push("/");
    } else {
      const userCode = sessionStorage.getItem("userCode");
      const patientCode = sessionStorage.getItem("patientCode");
      const accountType = sessionStorage.getItem("accountType");
      const accessTokenExpDate = Number(sessionStorage.getItem("expDate"));
      if (accessTokenExpDate * 1000 <= new Date().getTime()) {
        console.log("logging out -> token expired");
        this.props.signOut();
        this.props.history.push("/");
      } else {
        const userData = {
          accessToken,
          userCode,
          patientCode,
          accessTokenExpDate,
          accountType
        };
        this.props.onAuthSuccess(userData);
        this.props.lastVisitedPage === null
          ? this.props.history.push("/dashboard/home")
          : this.props.history.push(this.props.lastVisitedPage);
      }
    }
  }

  get authenticatedRoutes() {
    return (
      <AuthenticatedWrapper>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/dashboard/home" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route
            path="/dashboard/patient/:patientCode/profile"
            component={Profile}
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/dashboard/patient/:patientCode/edit"
            component={Dashboard}
          />
          <Route exact path="/contact" />
          <Route exact path="/doctors-portal" />
          <Route exact path="/signout" component={Signout} />
          <Route exact path="/404" component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
        {this.props.authStatus === "AUTHENTICATED" ? (
          <Watcher
            onSessionExpired={this.onSessionExpired}
            onUserInActivity={this.onUserInActivity}
          />
        ) : null}
      </AuthenticatedWrapper>
    );
  }

  get unAuthenticatedRoutes() {
    return (
      <UnAuthenticatedWrapper>
        <Switch>
          <Redirect exact from="/" to="/signin" />
          <Route exact path="/signin" component={Signin} />
          <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
          <Route exact path="/404" component={NotFound} />
          {/* <Redirect from="*" to="/404" /> */}
        </Switch>
      </UnAuthenticatedWrapper>
    );
  }

  onSessionExpired = () => {
    const { history } = this.props;
    history.push("/signout");
  };

  onUserInActivity = () => {
    const { history } = this.props;
    history.push("/signout");
  };

  render() {
    const { authStatus } = this.props;
    console.log("Auth:", authStatus);
    const headerClasses =
      this.props.location.pathname === "/signin" ? "blueLinks" : "whiteLinks";
    const appRoutes =
      authStatus === "AUTHENTICATED"
        ? this.authenticatedRoutes
        : this.unAuthenticatedRoutes;
    const navLinks = ["signin", "signup", "contact", "doctors-portal"];

    let header = <Header extraClasses={headerClasses} />;
    let sidebar = <Sidebar navLinks={navLinks} hasUserView={false} />;
    let mainClasses = classNames({
      "big-container": authStatus === "AUTHENTICATED" ? true : false
    });

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className={mainClasses}>
          {authStatus === "AUTHENTICATED" ? null : header}
          {authStatus === "AUTHENTICATED" ? null : sidebar}
          <BurgerIcon />
          <main>{appRoutes}</main>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Dashboard.js

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  state = {
    cities: [],
    areas: []
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    cmInit();
    dropDownInit();
    if (prevProps.searchResult.length !== this.props.searchResult.length) {
      this.handleRedirect("/dashboard/search");
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getDashboardData(this.props.patientCode);
  }

  handleRedirect(pathName) {
    this.props.history.push(pathName);
  }

  onSubmit = formData => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    this.props.onSearchSubmit(formData);
  };

  onGovernorateDropDownChange = e => {
    const gov = e.target.value;
    const cities = [];
    let areas = null;
    addresses.map(address => {
      if (address.governorate === gov) {
        address.cities.map(city => {
          cities.push(city.name);
          areas = city.areas;
        });
      }
    });
    this.setState({ cities, areas });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      accountType,
      handleSubmit,
      dashboardData,
      initialPage
    } = this.props;
    const specializations = ["allergy and immunology", "spec2", "spec3"];
    let dashboard = (
      <div className="dashboard">
        <div className="content">
          <div className="row row-margin">
            <div className="col l10 offset-m1 s12 person-banner">
              <p>
                Hello, {dashboardData !== null ? dashboardData.patientName : ""}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row row-margin">
            <div className="col l10 offset-m1 s12 appointments-banner">
              <h4>Appointments</h4>
              <AppointmentCard
                appointmentInfo={
                  dashboardData !== null
                    ? dashboardData.upcomingAppointment
                    : null
                }
                title="Next appointment"
              />
              <AppointmentCard
                appointmentInfo={
                  dashboardData !== null
                    ? dashboardData.previousAppointment
                    : null
                }
                title="Last appointment"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row row-margin">
            <div className="col l10 offset-m1 s12 search-banner">
              <h4>Search</h4>
              <SearchForm
                onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}
                onStarClick={this.onStarClick}
                addresses={addresses}
                areas={this.state.areas}
                cities={this.state.cities}
                specializations={specializations}
                onGovernorateDropDownChange={this.onGovernorateDropDownChange}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row row-margin">
            <div className="col l10 offset-m1 s12 doctors-banner">
              <h4>My doctors</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row row-margin">
            <div className="col l10 offset-m1 s12 rated-doctors-banner">
              <h4>Top rated doctors</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );

    if (this.props.isLoading) {
      dashboard = <Loader />;
    }

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Sidebar
          hasUserView={true}
          isFixed={true}
          accountType={accountType}
          extraClasses="hide-on-med-and-down"
        />
        {dashboard}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: also put last visited url into sessionstorage and redirect to that page if user authenticated

Comment: I saw this solution on the net but is it the best solution here?

Comment: When you refresh the page you lost the react state. It clears. So you have to put that info somewhere more persistent. I think the correct way is sessionstorage